# JQuery $_POST is not Working with WordPress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

This is my first time working with JQuery and I've been stuck on this point for hours.
I'm trying to make the like and dislike buttons like the ones you see on youtube under a video. After recording the click on like button I'm using $_POST method to add a new row in the likes table in my database. But there is something wrong. I've tried to track the problem and I know that for some reason the $_POST method is unable to run the "backgound.php" file. 
Below is my code.

```
<script  type="text/javascript">

    var user_liked = '<?php echo $user_liked; ?>';
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#li").click(function(){

        if(user_liked == '0') {
          $.post('<?php get_sport_you("backgound.php"); ?>' , {handle_like: 'increment'});
          user_liked = 1;
        } else {
          $.post('<?php get_sport_you("backgound.php"); ?>' , {handle_like: 'decrement'});
          user_liked = 0;
        }

      });
    });

  </script>
```

And this is the backgound.php

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

  if($_POST['handle_like'] === "increment") {
    submit_increment("user_likes", the_ID(), $_SESSION['u_id']);

  } else if($_POST['handle_like'] === "decrement"){
    submit_decrement("user_likes", the_ID(), $_SESSION['u_id']);
  }
}
 ?>
```

Comment: `$.POST` - Check the console.

Comment: Requests can be spoofed, use proper validation.

Comment: What functionality you wrote in `get_sport_you()` function?

Comment: @Nitin I'm working with WordPress on localhost. get_sport_you() method just return the complete path to the file. In this case, this is returned. 
http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/sportyou/backgound.php

Comment: These are the lines which create the button and the counter below it and its CSS.
`<span id="li"class="like"><i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i>
    <span id="lik" class="like-count"><?php echo $no_of_likes; ?></span></span>`
                                         
`.like{
      color:White;
      font-size: 1.5em;
    }`

And I'm using Font Awesome for Icons.

Comment: yes, I'm using WordPress.

Comment: What does var_dump($_POST) give you in the background.php file?;

Comment: @Script47 Session variables can't easily be spoofed. `$_SESSION['u_id']` should have been set when the user logged in.

Comment: It's not giving anything. That's the problem, whatever I put in backgroung.php is not executing.

Comment: @Barmar I said request referring to `$_POST['handle_like']`, not session.

Comment: @Barmar yes $_SESSION['u_id]  is set when the user logs in.

Comment: @Script47 Why does that matter?The user decides whether they like something, why does it matter if they spoof it?

Comment: @user8114666 Are there any errors in the console? Have you checked the Network tab to see if the AJAX request is sent?

Comment: @Script47 The value of 'handle_like' is not set by user data.

Comment: @Barmar it matters because if people can manipulate your data from outside of your application then clearly, it isn't ideal.

Comment: @Script47 I see what you mean. The application should only allow you to alternate between like and unlike, but you can spoof multiple likes.

Comment: @Barmar exactly, some sort of security token system would make it a lot harder to spoof.

Comment: Actually, it should just put `$user_liked` in a session variable.

Comment: @Barmar yes I checked the Network tab and calls are being made to background.php when I click the button.

Comment: What kind of element is `#li`? Is it a submit button in a form?

Comment: @Barmar `#li` is a simple span element. Form is not being used here.

Comment: Yuo never answered the earlier question, what does `var_dump($_POST)` show?

Comment: I can see `the_ID()`. Are you using WordPress?

Comment: @Barmar yes I tried it and it showed nothing.

Comment: @KrishnadasPC yes, I'm using wordpress.

Comment: Do any of your other scripts have problems like this?

Comment: _"I checked the Network tab and calls are being made to background.php"_ <- are the requests going to the correct URL? What is the response? Hint: you can see all this from the browser's _Network_ console. Also, you have not defined what is wrong? What isn't working? How do you know it's not working?

Comment: Also, have you fixed the typo from `$.POST` to `$.post` as pointed out in the very first comment? Are there any errors at all in the browser's _Console_?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your help. After a lot of head scratching, I was able to solve the problem. okay, Actually this is more of a WordPress problem than a jquery one.

`$.post('<?php get_sport_you("backgound.php"); ?>' , {handle_like: 'decrement'});`

The problem lies in the above statement, which interprets to this.

`$.post('localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/sportyou/backgound.php' , {handle_like: 'decrement'});`

In WordPress you just can't directly call PHP files first you have to create a page template first and then create a page from it. and then you can send a post request to it. The reason behind this is that if I just went directly calling the PHP file, many predefined WordPress functions won't work. e.g. add_action(), global $wpdb and you'll get all kinds of errors. These functions and objects just won't work and that's why I was unable to use $wpdb object to insert data into a table. Below is the correct version.

`$.post('http://localhost/mysite/background/' , {handle_like: 'decrement'});`